# how to send a flash message with res.redirect('/') sails js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

How to send a flash message with `res.redirect('/')` in Sails?

When i check some condition in a controller then I want to redirect to another url, passing along a flash message.

I am new to Sails, so any help will be appreciated.

Controller action:

```
module.exports ={
   index: function (req, res) {

    if(req.param('key')){
      req.flash('message', 'welcome key is present');
      res.redirect('/view/');
    } else {
      req.flash('message', 'welcome key is not present');
      res.redirect('/');
    }

  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your code looks fine for the controller.  In your view, you can access the flash message as `req.flash('message')`, so in an .ejs file for example it would be `<%- req.flash('message') %>`

Comment: oops sorry for that . i didn't know that if i once console log the flash then also it clear its value .

Comment: That messed me up too. I kept returning it in the console... sheesh!

Comment: Why I can't see the docs about 
[req.flash](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/request-req) ?

Answer (score 2):

What I find better for any redirect with data, is to set the http code to 307. It'll redirect with post/put/delete data.

```
req.flash('message');
res.redirect(307, '/');
```

Answer (score 1):

An other solution would be to pass the message parameter in the route where you render the redirected template.

So let's take your example (slightly modified):

```
module.exports ={
   index: function (req, res) {

    if(req.param('key')){
      req.flash('info', 'welcome key is present' );
      res.redirect('/view/');
    } else {
      req.flash('info', 'welcome key is not present');
      res.redirect('/');
    }

  }
}
```

Then in the route for 'view', you'll have something like this:

```
app.get('/view', function(req, res){
    var messages = {};
    if (typeof res.locals.messages.info != 'undefined'){
        messages = res.locals.messages.info;
    }
    res.render('view.ejs', {
        messages: messages
    });
});
```

Then in your view.ejs:

```
<% if (typeof messages != 'undefined' && messages.length > 0) { %>
            <% for (var i in messages) { %>
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    <%= messages[i] %>
                </div>
            <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Also in your main server.js file:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.messages = req.flash();
});
```